# How can I use the custom colors in Material Design 3?

Tags: android, material-design

Yesterday I upgraded my app from MD2 to MD3 and everything works well. But I still don't understand the custom colors in MD3.

**The Questions**

1. When should I use the custom colors? What is its real usage to it?
2. How should I use the custom colors?

I did not find anyone to explain how to use the custom colors on the internet.

Thank you.

Comment: You can add your color and download file from corner and add in your code(if required)-https://material-foundation.github.io/material-theme-builder/#/custom

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb Still did not answer my questions

Comment: What are you mean by custom colors? Are you meaning Dynamic Colors (Material You) or anything else?

Comment: @Sanjay I mean, I know how to create a custom role in Material Design 3, but I'm unsure how to apply it to components. I can't find anyone explaining this on the internet, and I don't know why.

Comment: what components app or sysyem like theme color

Comment: @TahaSami still can't understand what you are trying to say. By the way, if you are creating custom widgets with the help of material 3, some widgets has some restrictions regarding applying customization.

Comment: @Manjeetdeswal [Open the Material Theme Builder website](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom). There are four colors available: primary, secondary, tertiary, and neutral. Additionally, there are extended colors. If I add a new color to the extended colors, how can I use this extended color in an Android app?

Comment: @Sanjay Look at my previous reply

Comment: @TahaSami If you added those external color and exported, it will added to Colors.kt if you use jetpack compose and colors.xml if you use xml for designing, then you can call those colors normally like how you call.

Comment: I'm using XML. It is better to provide a full example in an answer. Let's suppose I added a new color called "Success." What is the best way to use these roles -> Success, on Success, Success container, on Success container with a button, for example?

Comment: @Sanjay Also, what is the meaning of "Harmonize" on the website above?

Comment: @TahaSami I have this article might help you in Harmonizing color for view https://codelabs.developers.google.com/harmonize-color-android-views#0

Comment: @TahaSami What do you mean by this? "What is the best way to use these roles -> Success, on Success, Success container, on Success container", are you named those colors as Success, Success container etc.,? And you need to know where should you use those colors as per Material Design rule? If yes the link I sent you in previous comment might help you. And also It will be tough for me without knowing the actual color value you have used.

Comment: @Sanjay The tutorial link you shared is helpful. Consider posting it as an answer, and I will mark it as the correct answer.